Dynamically manage state for rows in react-table
Columns data which is memoised
const Columns = useMemo(() => {
    return {
        // somecolumns
      comments: {
        Header: "Coments",
        accessor: "comments",
        width: "250",
        Cell: (props) => {
          const index = props.row.index
          const comments = props.data[index].comments || []
          const orderID = props.data[index].id || ""

          const onCommentChange = (comment : string) => {
            setOrders(getRefreshedOrdersForComments(orders, orderID, comment))
          }

          return 
             
                <Comment
                  comments={
                    comments.latest_comment ? [comments.latest_comment] : []
                  }
                  count={comments.no_of_comments}
                  orderID={orderID}
                  successCallback={onCommentChange}
                  orders={editOrder}
                />
               
          
        },
      }, // somecolumns
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [orderID, orders])

Table component
<Table
    data={orders}
    columns={columns}
 />

Comment component which has list of orders from table and orderID is for individual row.
const Comment= ({ comments, orders, orderId, count , successCallback }) => {
   const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)
   const onAdd = useCallback((e) => {
     e.stopPropagation()
     setEditMode(true)
   }, [orderID])
   return {editMode && (
            <CommentEditor
              comment={""}
              onCancel={(e) => onCancel(e)}
              onSave={onSave}
              awaitingStatus={awaitingResponse || ""}
            />
          )}
          {isWriteAllowed && (
                  <div
                    data-testid="latest-comment-add-new"
                    className={`${Styles["comment-edit"]} ignore_row_click`}
                    onClick={onAdd}
                  >
                    Add
                  </div>
                )}
}

Onclick of add the comment box opens but when i click the next add button the previous comment box is still open. How to go about it ? Tried lot of stuff not working. The issue is we are using reactTable V7.
